# Title text cut out in Android Notch Phone in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing on flutter based hybrid mobile app on which I am using **Google Pixel XL** API 28 
emulator.
The application works fine but my title on the application is cut due to notch of the screen.
I have tried to add a **safe area** too but could not get success. Anyone have any idea of this.
Thanks in advance.

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: hey, Can you show us the code. how you used safeArea?

Comment: use `SafeArea` widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!! 
I found the solutions.

Create one folder inside Android res's folder with the name of **"values-v28"**
Copy the code from **Values** folder's styles.xml file and paste it into new folder or replace the below code inside the new folder's styles.xml file.
Force quit terminal which you used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It works for me.
thanks for your valuable respose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SafeArea" Like Below Code:-

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container()),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put Scaffold into safe area

```
 return SafeArea(    
 child: Scaffold  ( ),
 );
```